# After login redirect a customer to a cms page if customer belongs to a particular group

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, redirect, login

I want to redirect a customer to a cms page if customer belongs to a particular customer group.

In config.xml:

```
            <customer_login>
                <observers>
                    <after_customer_login>
                        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>afterCustomerLoggedIn</method>
                    </after_customer_login>
                </observers>
            </customer_login>
```

In Observer.php:

```
public function afterCustomerLoggedIn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    Mage::log("Yes customer is logged in." , null, "my.log");

    $groupId = $customer->getData('group_id');
    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
    $customer_group = $group->getCode();

    if($customer_group == "My_group")
    {
        $redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('mypage');
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For redirect url:

```
Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl("cms-page-identifier"));
```

Your observer code as below:

```
public function afterCustomerLoggedIn(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
    Mage::log("Yes customer is logged in." , null, "my.log");

    $groupId = $customer->getData('group_id');
    $group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);
    $customer_group = $group->getCode();

    if($customer_group == "My_group")
    {
        $redirect_url = Mage::getUrl('mypage');
       Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirect_url)->sendResponse(); 
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not redirecting.

Comment: Update answer with working code.Check it hope it will helpful to you.